# signed volume for tetrahedra, n-simplices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

For a triangle in 2D, it is customary to define the signed area to be positive if the points are indexed counterclockwise (mathematically positive). For n-simplices in nD, there are the formulae
$$
\frac{1}{n!}
\det\begin{pmatrix}
v_0 & \dots & v_n\\
1 & \dots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{n!}
\det\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 - v_0 & \dots & v_n - v_0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
They give the same results for 2D triangles, but given different results (in sign) for tets and higher-order cells.

Is there a canonical rule for n-simplices in nD, or perhaps at least for tetrahedra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of a one-dimensional integral $[a,b]$, the expressions in  the original question give
$$
\frac{1}{n!} \det\begin{pmatrix}b - a\end{pmatrix} = b - a
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{n!} \det\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} = a - b,
$$
respectively. In light of the fact that most everyone wants the area of $[a,b]$ to be positive iff $a < b$, we can say that the first expression is more "canonical".

The second can be remedied by adding a sign factor,
$$
V = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \det\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

With this, the following orderings have positive volume:

[image]

[image]